# Ogr2ogr transform shapefile into GeoJSON without the geometry

Tags: gdal, ogr2ogr

I'm trying to transform a set of shapefiles (49) that contains nearly 2500 LineStrings each and also different columns of information.

So my intention is to obtain only this additional information from the shapefile without all the geometries. For this I tried to transform the Shapefiles in GeoJSON (to later use inside some scripts with PHP) with ogr2ogr.

The command I tried is:

```
ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON  <geoJsonFile> <inputShape> -nlt NONE
```

So far this has worked perfectly in a local environment where I have ogr2ogr version 2.2. But in the server that I need to run the scripts (that has ogr2ogr version 1.9) it seems like the -nlt option is beeing ignored, as the resulting GeoJSON files still contains all the geometries.

I tried checking the documentation but it doesn't seem to be an issue with the version as the -nlt NONE option seems to be available just fine.

Is there any other reason why this may not be working as expected? Or maybe another parameter to achieve the same goal?

- As a side note, I can't update the version that is available at that server, so updating to a newer version is out of my scope.

Comment: you can try using a pseudo sql command using the -sql  flag and select all your fields but the geometry.

Comment: Or even simpler, use the -select flag and parse a list of your fields except the geometry.

Comment: I tried both, and it select only the field that I want. But its still including the geometry in the GeoJson file

Comment: We've been testing with other formats and transforming into CSV instead of GeoJson seems to work just fine with the -nlt NONE.  It seems to be an issue with the version of ogr2ogr. Thanks